# QbyteArray data copy

Tags: qt, qbytearray

I have two `QByteArray`, `sData` and `dData`.

I want to copy `n` bytes from location `x` in `dData` i.e. `&dData[x]` to location `y` of `sData` i.e. `&sData[y]`.

In C, array copy is done by `memcpy(&dData[x], &sData[y], n);`

How could copying above data of `QByteArray` be done in Qt?

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather an important consideration: please remember that QByteArray's raw data facility allows you to use a QByteArray object as a front for a C array. It __doesn't copy__ anything from the said raw data, and you can't pass such QByteArray object away from the scope in which raw data exists.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbytearray.html#replace), you can use the replace function: -

```
QByteArray & QByteArray::replace(int pos, int len, const QByteArray & after)
```

> Replaces len bytes from index position pos with the byte array after, and returns a reference to this byte array.

So, using the overload

```
QByteArray & QByteArray::replace(int pos, int len, const char * after);

sData = sData.replace(y, nBytes, dData.constData()+x);
```

Comment: am I need to reserve memory before replace?

Answer (score 6):

Besides the given answer you could also use `memcpy` and the `QByteArray::data()` member to get a pointer to the internal array. Of course you are then responsible that the size of the destination array is big enough to hold all copied data from the source array.

```
memcpy(dest.data() + y, src.constData() + x, n)
```

Comment: If there is a memcpy C++ alternative, we should use the alternative like setRawData or replace

Answer (score -1):

If you want to copy data from index zero, there is a function for that:

```
sData.setRawData(dData, n);
```

Comment: FYI: This answer is misleading because the data is NOT copied. The Qt documentation for setRawData states: "The bytes are not copied. The QByteArray will contain the data pointer. The caller guarantees that data will not be deleted or modified as long as this QByteArray and any copies of it exist that have not been modified."